# Converting Firebase data into Swift array

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my Firebase data looks like:

```js
[ {
  "adress" : "Högåsstigen 10 332 33 Gislaved",
  "helg" : "18:00-02:00",
  "latitude" : 57.2985,
  "longitude" : 13.54326,
  "namn" : "Restaurang Åsen",
  "outlet" : 0,
  "phone" : "0371-123456",
  "star" : 0,
  "tag" : "Restaurang",
  "vardag" : "10:00-19:30"
}, {
  "adress" : "Högåsstigen 12 332 33 Gislaved",
  "helg" : "18:00-02:00",
  "latitude" : 57.9985,
  "longitude" : 13.94326,
  "namn" : "Kalles ställe",
  "outlet" : 0,
  "phone" : "0371-123456",
  "star" : 2,
  "tag" : "Restaurang",
  "vardag" : "10:00-19:30"
}, {
  "adress" : "Högåsstigen 15 332 33 Gislaved",
  "helg" : "18:00-02:00",
  "latitude" : 55.603384,
  "longitude" : 13.020619,
  "namn" : "Olles Pub",
  "outlet" : 0,
  "phone" : "0371-123456",
  "star" : 1,
  "tag" : "Krog",
  "vardag" : "10:00-19:30"
} ]
```

I want to grab "adress" from the database.

I'm having problem to convert the data I grab from Firebase to append into an array so I can use them later. I get the error "Value of type 'String' has no member 'generator'".

I have no idea how to proceed in my coding, any suggestions?

```
var adresserArray = [String]()

let ref = Firebase(url: "https://HIDINGMYURL.firebaseio.com/")

ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {snapshot in
    let adresser = (snapshot.value.objectForKey("adress")) as! String!

    for add in adresser{
        adresserArray.append(adresser)
    }
})
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Done, however Peter K helped me but I get some wierd data when I print my array after using his advice, example below. Maybe you have an idea.

Thanks Frank.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate over String here

```
let adresser = (snapshot.value.objectForKey("adress")) as! String!

for add in adresser{
   adresserArray.append(adresser)
}
```

try just replace this code with

```
let adresser = (snapshot.value.objectForKey("adress")) as! String
adresserArray.append(adresser)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, however I get some wierd converting...

It's like 3 or 4 arrays or [] in there, any idea why?

["Högåsstigen 10 332 33 Gislaved"]
["Högåsstigen 10 332 33 Gislaved", "Högåsstigen 12 332 33 Gislaved"]
["Högåsstigen 10 332 33 Gislaved", "Högåsstigen 12 332 33 Gislaved", "Högåsstigen 15 332 33 Gislaved"]

Comment: Could you show more code where dos you get this result?

Comment: I used - print(self.adresserArray) directly under the code you wanted me to replace. Then I get the last thing I commented in my console...

Comment: Seems like I get it. Your code inside  ref.observeEventType callback block runs on every child added, so if you add print inside, you will print this array after each dress insert. Your log is just 3 sprints of array 1 st time with one dress second with 2 etc.

Comment: What should I do to make it look normal so I can actually use the addresses  later on?

Comment: You can try something like that `ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {snapshot in
let adresser = (snapshot.value.objectForKey("adress")) as! String
adresserArray.append(adresser)
}) print(adresserArray)`

Comment: As I understand this block will run asynchronously so right after function call this black isn't called. But after it is called you can use you array with data. It is hard to guess what do you need exactly in your case, but it will be helpful if you read more about working with asynchronous calls in iOS and swift.